# Retrofit - MongoDB - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, mongodb, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to recieve some data from a mongodb. 
This is the formatting, I receive:

```
 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "56906e7ee4b0166e3b6a1a4a"
  },
  "plant": [
    {
      "documentId": "8923597",
      "latitude": "51.504169",
      "longitude": "7.462922",
      "stage": "4",
      "seeds": "erdbeere",
      "createAt": "08.01.2016",
      "seedColor": "red"
    },
    {
      "documentId": "5340284",
      "latitude": "51.5147365",
      "longitude": "7.4640148",
      "stage": "1",
      "seeds": "chili",
      "createAt": "24.12.2015",
      "seedColor": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using retrofit to get it.

```
MongolabDocumentConnector jsonConnection =
 retrofit.create(MongolabDocumentConnector.class);

Call call = 
 jsonConnection.contributors("myDBData", "myCollection", "myDocumentkey", "myApiKey");
```

My Structure looks like this:

```
public class PlantDBStructure {
public final float lat;
public final float lon;
public final int stage;
public final String seeds;
public final Date created;
public final Color seedColor;

public PlantDBStructure(float lat, float lon, int stage, String seeds, Date created, Color seedColor) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon=lon;
    this.stage=stage;
    this.seeds=seeds;
    this.created=created;
    this.seedColor=seedColor;
 }
}
```

When I run the code I get the exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $...

I know I have to change the PlantDBStructure, but I don't really know how.
Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you retrieving one document from the database, or a list of documents?

Comment: The crucial part so see here would be the `interface` where you are declaring your Retrofit methods, i. e. `MongolabDocumentConnector` - maybe you only need to chage the return value there. It seems Retrofit - or, to be more precise, Gson - is trying to interpret your JSON as an Array of something when it actually is only one object.

Comment: Just a guess: You are telling Retrofit to return a `List<PlantDBStructure>` when in reality the JSON represents some other object that *contains* that list under the key `plant`.